# Fetching 50000 records at time using soql

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, socrata

I am using the below code to get the records from a dataset having 500k records in my asp.net mvc app.

```
  var soqlCountry = new SoqlQuery().Select(columns).Limit(50000)
```

But this returns only 1000 records.
How to get 50000 records please help??

Comment: Can you please provide more information about your request? What dataset are you calling, what columns are you passing in your `Select`, etc.

Comment: I am calling a private dataset. I am passing 21 columns which are of datatype string..

Answer (score 0):

The `SoqlQuery` class was limiting you to 1000 internally. I've sent the developer of `SODA.NET` a [a pull request](https://github.com/CityofSantaMonica/SODA.NET/pull/40) to fix that.

In the meantime, you can try out [my branch](https://github.com/chrismetcalf/SODA.NET).

Comment: The fix has been merged, and a hotfix v0.4.1 released to Nuget! Thanks @salman